# Is the rank of this group always finite? Why?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Take $U$ an open subset of the plane. Consider $C_0(U)$ the free abelian group over the points of $U$, $C_1(U)$ the free abelian group over continuous paths (i.e. continuous maps $[0,1]\to U$), and $C_2(U)$ the free abelian group over continuous maps $[0,1]\times[0,1]\to U$. Consider the maps $\partial_1:C_1\to C_0$ given by:

$$\partial_1\left(\sum_ia_i\gamma_i\right)=\sum_ia_i(\gamma_i(1)-\gamma_i(0)),$$

and $\partial_2:C_2\to C_1$ given by:

$$\partial_2\left(\sum_ia_iR_i\right)=\sum_ia_i\partial R_i,$$

where the $\partial_2$ of a single map $R$ from $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ is:

$$\partial_2R=R|_{[0,1]\times\{0\}}+R|_{\{0\}\times[0,1]}-R|_{[0,1]\times\{1\}}-R|_{\{1\}\times[0,1]}.$$

Define:

$$H_0(U):=\frac{C_0(U)}{\operatorname{Im}\partial_1},\qquad H_1(U):=\frac{\ker\partial_1}{\operatorname{Im}\partial_2}.$$

Can we prove that either of these has finite rank for any open $U$? How?

Comment: Take $U = \mathbb R^2 \backslash \mathbb Z^2$. $H_1(U)$ has no finite rank.

Comment: @N.H. That $U$ is not a subset of the plane and $H_1(U)$ has rank $2$.

Comment: @Goa'uld what? $\mathbb{R}^2\smallsetminus\mathbb{Z}^2$ certainly is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and I bet $H_1(\mathbb{R}^2\smallsetminus\mathbb{Z}^2)$ has infinite rank, since I'm sure the circumferences of radius $\frac12$ around any $(m,n)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ are distinct equivalence classes of $H_1(U)$. Then again, I see N.H. used `\backslash` ($\backslash$) while I just typed `\smallsetminus` ($\smallsetminus$), so perhaps we interpreted the comment differently, with the $\backslash$ hinting at some quotient?

Comment: And that quotient would be the torus, right? I know that $\pi_1$ of the torus is $\mathbb{Z}^2$, so maybe one could work out $H_1$ also is.

Comment: Btw does this kind of homology have its own name? I ask this so that next time I need to refer to this in a post I can say "<foo> homology group" instead of defining it again.

Comment: @N.H. did you mean a quotient or a set difference? I am guessing the second…

Comment: I see, yes, I interpreted it as the torus. But if it is the difference, then it was correct, sorry.

Comment: @MickG I believe it is called cubical homology or cubic singular homology.

Comment: As MikG said $U$ is not the torus but the plane minus the integer points, which has infinite $H_1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply take $U = \{ (a,b) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid (a,b) \notin \mathbb Z^2\}$. This space has infinite-rank first homology group.